# Update default column values for libraries in different sites collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

Hello I am working on a powershell script to update the default values for a specific column (Year) from 2016 to 2017. 
We have several project sites (each projectsite is a sitecollection). I would like to update all the column values for all the sites in the different site collections

I have created the following, but isn't working:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/sites"
$sitelists = foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
foreach($list in $web.lists){ $list }}
$list = $Web.Lists["Documents"]
$field = $list.Fields["Year"]
$field.DefaultValue = "2017"
$field.Update()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store a loop in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint"
$l = $w.lists["Shared Documents"]
$f = $l.Fields["Year"]
$f.DefaultValue = "2017"
$f.Update()
```

Or this:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$site = Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint"
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
    foreach($list in $web.lists){
        $list = $Web.Lists["Documents"]
        $field = $list.Fields["Year"]
        $field.DefaultValue = "2017"
        $field.Update()
    }
}
```

One more example:

```
$allWebs = Get-SPWebApplication "http://yourWebAPP" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All 

foreach($web in $allWebs)
{
     foreach($list in $web.lists){
        $list = $Web.Lists["Documents"]
        $field = $list.Fields["Year"]
        $field.DefaultValue = "2017"
        $field.Update()
    }
}
```

You will want to add error handling, checking if objects exists, and disposing of objects.

Comment: Is not working, we have a web-application http://XXX.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com within that webapp we have several sitecollections. Get the following error: The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: Try the first example on a single Web, then let me know.

Comment: This is working for one specific site collection Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$w = Get-SPWeb "http://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/sites/project1"
$l = $w.lists["Documents"]
$f = $l.Fields["Year"]
$f.DefaultValue = "2017"
$f.Update()

Comment: Then a point to a specific sitecollection, but would like to use the script to walk through all my site collections. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added another example that gets the web app, sites, and webs.  After that, it will loop through the webs, then lists.